# When to use long or int in Kotlin? Is there any difference in performance?

Tags: kotlin, oop

I was supporting a system made in Kotlin, and I noticed that some variables with integer values ​​are as int, while others are as long. Is there any difference in the use of the two types, considering the system performance?

For example:

`val id: Long = 0, val age: Int = 0,`

Why use different types in these cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Studying about "primitive types" in Kotlin (in quotation marks, as Kotlin does not have primitive types, the language uses classes for this), basically the difference between Int and Long is the amount of bits that each type can store.

**Int:**

- Size: 32 bits
- Possible values: from -2174483648 to 2147483647

**Long:**

- Size: 64 bits
- Possible values: from -9223372036854770000 to 9223372036854770000

Therefore, if you store a value referring to age (something that varies between 0 and 120) in a variable of type Long, you will be mismanaging your system's memory resources, considering that a variable of type Int, which consumes Less memory would solve your problem.

Comment: That’s not necessarily true. On 64-bit systems, sometimes the implementation aligns the memory on 64-bit words for performance reasons, so using Ints doesn’t save memory vs Longs except in IntArrays. In some implementations using Ints could negatively impact performance as well because they don’t align with word size. This is however extreme optimization to worry about and would be JVM implementation dependent.

Comment: Note that when Kotlin is targeting the JVM, then `Int` / `Long` in non-generic contexts really _are_ primitive types. Not sure what happens when targeting other platforms.